# The operation has timed out in windows forms

Tags: asp.net, service, ado.net, httprequest, telegram-bot

i used this code in windows service and windows application, and i enforce 'the operation has timed out', but when i used this code in website, i never enforce exception, what's problem?!

```
string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TelegramServiceConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  SH_Message_Sent.phone, SH_Message_Sent.text, SH_Message_Sent.update_id, FaranegarApiUsers.chat_id, FaranegarApiUsers.phone AS Expr1 FROM         SH_Message_Sent INNER JOIN FaranegarApiUsers ON SH_Message_Sent.phone = FaranegarApiUsers.phone  where SH_Message_Sent.phone='09127218155' order by update_id asc ", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable t = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
        {
            WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://api.telegram.org/bot99452812:AAE2MntQnStPr_J2KmrOsp_gvGZLZNsy3mE/sendMessage?chat_id=" + row[3] + "&text=" + row[1]);
            request2.Timeout = 20000;
            WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modify my code and its works correctly
 
   `WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://api.telegram.org/bot99452812:AAE2MntQnStPr_J2KmrOsp_gvGZLZNsy3mE/sendMessage?chat_id=" + row[3] + "&text=" + row[1]);
            request2.Timeout = 20000;
            WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
response2.Close();`